# mvn test does not launch Test NG tests but shows Build Successful

Tags: maven, testng

When running my Maven project with `mvn test` and `testing.xml`, my tests are not launched. But build shows successful. I have included necessary `maven-surefire-plugin`. Pls can anybody help.

[image: The project structure]

Content `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.siemens.fossology.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ui-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <main.class>com.siemens.fossology.test.ui.StartUp</main.class>

        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <config-builder.version>1.3.1</config-builder.version>
        <testng.version>6.1.1</testng.version>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.8</mockito.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <selenium-java.version>2.47.1</selenium-java.version>
        <xml-apis.version>1.4.01</xml-apis.version>

        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>config-builder</artifactId>
            <version>${config-builder.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>${xml-apis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId> <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId> 
            <version>2.16</version> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org/xmlsoap/schemas/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>org/apache/ws/commons/schema/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The `testing.xml` content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite verbose="0" name="Default suite">
    <test verbose="2" name="Default test" preserve-order="false">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.siemens.fossology.test.ui.scripts.AdminCleanupTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: My testing.xml file runs successfully if i run as TestNg  suite.(attached)    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"> 
<suite verbose="0" name="Default suite"> 
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test" preserve-order="false"> 
    <classes> 
        <class name="com.siemens.fossology.test.ui.scripts.AdminCleanupTest"/> 
 </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>

Comment: where is your testing.xml ? src/test/resources

Comment: I added the image for path of testing.xml

Comment: Have you run it with `mvn -X -e clean test` ? Just to follow better what is going on.

Comment: Yes i run the above command. But still same result, build successful, no tests launched.

Comment: But i get a message in console saying : skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\fossology-ui-testing\tngfossy-fossology-ui-testing-e6d25891f70f\src\test\resources. Is this message is causing any issue. This appears along with Build Success message.

Comment: Can anybody pls help ! i am blocked..Waiting for the answer.

Comment: Yes, can be, just to check, add the missing directory. I've seen similar issues, because a directory did not exist. Pls check it. We can search for the fix, once we know if that really is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Changing maven-surefire-plugin version to 2.14.1 in pom.xml has solved the issue. Now my mvn test launches TestNG tests.Verhagen, juherr Thanks for the inputs. But still i dont know why it expected this version?

Comment: Are you now (2015.10) using the latest version (2.18.1) ?

Comment: I did not get you.. Do i need to use 2.18.1 ?

Comment: I am now using 2.14.1

Comment: Changing maven-surefire-plugin version to 2.14.1 solved my issue.

Comment: Very strange. I was using `3.2.1` and changed to `2.14.1`, and now is working.

Answer (score 1):

Move `testing.xml` in `src/test/resources/` directory

and then change pom with:

```
<suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
```

Comment: did this, didnt helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In an other project I see the doctype defined as:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Where you have

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Could that be the cause ?

Comment: Hi Verhagen, Thanks for noticing. Yes the header of my testing.xml is wrong. It should be <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM " http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >. But this      throws TestNG exception. i corrected it.( I mean missing http: in begining)

Comment: Try removing the complete `<!DOCTYPE ... >` line complete, and see if that solves the issue.`

Answer (score 0):

Just modify each `.class` file name to finish with the word test.

Example:

```
FirstLoginTest.class

GetCustomersTest.class
```